# Android - Get gallery images Samsung S4/S5

Tags: android, gallery, galaxy

I'm working on a custom image gallery for my application but I got a serious issue under Samsung Galaxy S4 and S5. The following code works great on HTC and Xperia devices but not at all on Samsung ones.

Basically, the pathes are always `null` on these devices.
Here is the code I made.
In big lines, it returns a list of categories containing a name and a list of images. The aim is to provide a folder based gallery like the native one.

**Should you have any idea why it fails on Samsung galaxy ?**

Thanks for your help.

```
public List<Category> getCategories()
{
    Map<String, Category> map = new HashMap<String, Category>();

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
    };

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
    if (cursor == null) return;

    if (cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        Category category = null;
        long id = 0L;
        String bucket = null;;
        int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

        do
        {
            id = cur.getLong(idColumn);
            bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);

            if (map.get(bucket) == null)
            {
                category = new Category(bucket);
                map.put(bucket, category);
            }
            category = map.get(bucket);

            category.addImage( idToImage(id) );
        }
        while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

    return map.values().toArray();
}

private Image idToImage(long id)
{
    Image image = new Image();

    image.setThumbnail( getThumbnail(id) );
    image.setImage( getImage(id) );

    return image;
}

private String getThumbnail(long id)
{
    String path = null;
    Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
    if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 )
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
        cursor.close();
    }

    return path;
}

private String getImage(long id)
{
    String path = null;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String where = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, where, null, null);
    int dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 )
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        path = cursor.getString(dataColumn);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work

```
/**
 * Get actual file path from gallery
 */
public String getPath(Uri uri, Context ctx) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```